# Scroll lock all elements above a certain location in a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css, gwt

I have a web appplication and when scrolling I want to lock everything above a certain pixel. Is this in any way possible ?

The problem is I have a Grid showing data somewhere on the screen.
When scrolling the contents of the Grid should scroll, but everything above the Grid should just remain locked on screen.
The Grid is always at a different location. So, for example, I want to be able to just say : "Scroll lock all elements that are above pixel 135".

The web application was built using GWT.
So any answer solving this in either GWT, HTML, CSS or JavaScript is accepted.

Comment: Add an overflow to the grid itself ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want an element in the same position you must to use position fixed. Even you can add a js function if you want an specific behavior in an element using scroll property, at this you can specify when users are scrolling in an specific pixel: example:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    //instructions when you are scrolling.
 })
```